# Uploading avi file to AWS S3 using aws-cpp-sdk

Tags: c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I tried to upload an avi file to aws s3 storage using the following code.

```
#include <aws/core/utils/HashingUtils.h>
#include <aws/core/Aws.h>
#include <aws/s3/S3Client.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.h>
#include <aws/s3/model/CreateBucketRequest.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace Aws::S3::Model;
using namespace std;
using namespace Aws::Utils;

static const char* KEY = "test.avi";//"s3_cpp_sample_key";
static const char* BUCKET = "testnmn";//"s3-cpp-sample-bucket";

int main()
{

    Aws::SDKOptions options;
    Aws::InitAPI(options);   


    const Aws::String key_name = KEY;
    const Aws::String dir_name = "/home/Softwares/Projects/S3upload/build";

    Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client;
    Aws::S3::Model::CreateBucketRequest bucket_request;
    bucket_request.WithBucket("testavinmn");
    auto create_bucket_outcome1 = s3_client.CreateBucket(bucket_request);
    if(create_bucket_outcome1.IsSuccess()) {
        std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "CreateBucket error: " <<
            create_bucket_outcome1.GetError().GetExceptionName() << std::endl <<
            create_bucket_outcome1.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
    }

    Aws::S3::Model::PutObjectRequest object_request;
    object_request.WithBucket("testavinmn").WithKey(key_name);

    auto input_data = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::FStream>(key_name.c_str(), dir_name.c_str(), std::ios_base::in);
    object_request.SetBody(input_data);
    object_request.SetContentType("avi");
    object_request.SetContentLength(static_cast<long>(object_request.GetBody()->tellg()));
    object_request.SetContentMD5(HashingUtils::Base64Encode(HashingUtils::CalculateMD5(*object_request.GetBody())));
    auto put_object_outcome = s3_client.PutObject(object_request);

    if(put_object_outcome.IsSuccess()) {
        std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
    }
    else {
         std::cout << "PutObject error: " <<
             put_object_outcome.GetError().GetExceptionName() << " " <<
             put_object_outcome.GetError().GetMessage() << std::endl;
    }

    Aws::ShutdownAPI(options);

    return 0;  
}
```

The code has a few issues.

(1)The first one is it has to create a bucket and put the object into a newly created bucket.
It can't put object into an existing bucket.
The reason could be because of the region of the existing bucket.
How can I select the region of the existing bucket so that the object can be put into that existing bucket? Any C++ api for that?

(2)Second problem is the uploaded object has 0byte data. For that the problem could be input_data  has to open and read the file to upload. How can I open and read the file in aws-cpp-sdk?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For setting your region, you can use the ClientConfiguration struct and pass the object when creating the S3 Client as:

```
Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration myConf;
myConf.region = Aws::Region::US_WEST_2;
Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(myConf);
```

Regarding the 0 bytes issue, as a workaround, you can try using a std::fstream object and set the content length:

```
auto input_data = std::make_shared<std::fstream> (key_name.c_str(),std::ios_base::in);
input_data->seekp(0, std::ios_base::end);
object_request.SetBody(input_data);
object_request.SetContentLength(static_cast<long>(object_request.GetBody()->tellp()));
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first issue:
If the other answer didn't work, try setting the endpointOverride variable to contain the full path to your bucket:

```
Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration cc;
cc.region = Aws::Region::EU_WEST_1;
cc.endpointOverride = "s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<bucket_name>";
Aws::S3::S3Client s3_client(cc);
```

Regarding your second issue, you can use a regular C++ fstream, and open it using ios_base::ate flag:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::fstream> input_data =
     std::make_shared<std::fstream>(full_path.c_str(),
          std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::ate);
object_request.SetContentLength(input_data->tellg());
object_request.SetBody(input_data);
```